# EC2- Is Run Commands available on Debian instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, debian

Do I understand correctly that I can't use the "Run commands" feature on my Debian EC2 instance?

This page does not include Debian:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/remote-commands-prereq.html

I tried the Ubuntu setup, after downloading the package (which says DEBIAN), I ran this:

```
dpkg -i /tmp/ssm/amazon-ssm-agent.deb
```

And got this error:

```
(Reading database ... 49940 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack /tmp/ssm/amazon-ssm-agent.deb ...
Stopping agent
/var/lib/dpkg/info/amazon-ssm-agent.prerm: 2: /var/lib/dpkg/info/amazon-ssm-agent.prerm: stop: not found
...
```

If it is NO compatible with Debian, then is there any rational?
Is AWS recommending Ubunte over Debian?

Comment: This question MAY be off topic and better suited for serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

It will run on Debian Jessie but you need to create a systemd service configuration for it.  Fortunately Amazon has already created one for RHEL and CentOS. Just use the amazon-ssm-agent.service file from the RPM.